# This is causing my page to load very slow or not at all?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, try-catch

I just updated from php 5.3.4 to 5.3.8. After the update it seems that all my code that includes **try{** causes my page to hang and use up all my server memory.

```
if(preg_match('/^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}$/', $ip)){
$xml = @file_get_contents('http://' . $this->service . '/' . $this->version . '/' . $name . '/?key=' . $this->apiKey . '&ip=' . $ip . '&format=xml');
try{
$response = @new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach($response as $field=>$value){
$result[(string)$field] = (string)$value; }
return $result;
}
catch(Exception $e){ $this->errors[] = $e->getMessage();
return;
}
}
```

This also causes a major issues

```
<?php

try{
$gt = new Gtranslate;
$gt->setRequestType('curl');

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM PAGE_CONTENT WHERE live_page = '1'";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
$page_id_sub = $row["page_id"];
$page_title = $row["page_title"];
$page_permalink = $row["page_permalink"];

if(empty($mylang)){
echo "<a href='/$permalink/$page_permalink.html'>$page_title</a> |";
}
else {
$page_trans = $gt->$mylang("$page_title");
echo "<a href='/$permalink/$page_permalink.html'>$page_trans</a> |";
}
}
}
catch (GTranslateException $ge){
echo $ge->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has very little to do with `try` and much more to do with your remote requests (i.e. `file_get_contents()` and `$gt->$mylang()`).

As a benchmark, remove those lines and see how your page performs. If they are indeed the culprit, you may want to consider caching their response or some other approach so your not making the request on every page load.

Comment: You are right, I commented out $xml = @file_get_contents('http://' . $this->service . '/' . $this->version . '/' . $name . '/?key=' . $this->apiKey . '&ip=' . $ip . '&format=xml'); and the page loaded fine. But why did it work before and how can I fix it?

Comment: I replaced file_get_contents with simplexml_load_file. Made the pages load faster but still a little slow

Comment: If nothing else changed on the server, *maybe* you could look into the PHP upgrade. But I think it's likely a fluke. You could always remove the `try/catch` or error suppression. The latter is ill advised anyway.